# Is there a way to use the Python Interpreter with (or within) my file?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Basically, I'm learning to code and I like to test stuff, like, how to use a class, what can I access in which circumstances, etc, etc. So I run my scripts multiple times with slight variations, and that could be a bit tedious.

So what I did is this loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        exec(input(''))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'xx {e}')
```

This solves the initial problem... Now I can input Python code to test, and it will have all my classes and variables ready to be accesed. So I basically recreated a very basic version of the Python CLI.

I've worked out some extra functionality out of it, but I'm basically reverse engineering the existing CLI , and I don't think that this is a useful way to go. And copy/pasting big chunks of code directly doesn't work most of the time. So I ask:

Is there a way to run a script, and have the CLI ready to be interacted with?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using a IPython or a Jupyter (lab) notebook instead?

Comment: If the CLI you're trying to reverse engineer is in pure python and CPython based, it'll be a lot easier (in terms of future tech debt) to just read the code and understand it than to wrap around with more python popen/os cli runs.

Comment: @alvas Sorry, I think I didn't explain myself properly, I'm not trying to reverse engineer anything, is just that I realized that the functionalities I need to test stuff already exist in the CLI, and it's probably unnecessary for me to program them from scratch.